# How to add a border to a background-image that contains a svg?

Tags: css, svg, background-image, border

Like the headline I have the problem to get a border around my background-image that contains a svg.
When I try to use css border on that background-image then the border will go inwards and decrease the image.
I've read something about using svg:image but that seems for me that I have to edit the svg code itselfs to get a border.
Isn't there any solution to do it with CSS?

**Solved**

Thank you for your answers. But as I said I don't want to change anything inside the svg file.
I found a working solution for myself.

```
.s-icon {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
}

.s-icon--border {
  background-color: lightblue;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 0;
  border: 4px solid lightskyblue;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRBQoE

Comment: Can you provide your code on jsfiddle or plunker with your try :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Draw a `<rect>` round the image which is fill="none". You can use the stroke of the `<rect>` as the border.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with box-shadow

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```